# What cmake command is matched vpath at GNU make?

Tags: cmake

I am rewriting a cmake build script from an existing GNU makefile. It is the first cmake scrip I have tried to write.

GNU make provide vpaths command, but i can not find a corrsponding command.

I have implemented a macro to resolve it, but i am finding it too hard to cover all exception cases.

Do you have any solution for it?

---

It takes some time under many source and dir.

macro( vpath resultSource NumOfSource NumOfDir sourceList DirList )
    math(EXPR startDirIndex "3 + ${NumOfSource}" )
    math(EXPR endIndex "2 + ${NumOfSource} + ${NumOfDir}" )

```
message(STATUS "startDirIndex: ${startDirIndex}")
message(STATUS "endIndex: ${endIndex}")

set( __SRC_LIST__ )
set( __SRC_DIR__ )

set( pos 0 )
foreach(item ${ARGV})
    if( ${pos} EQUAL ${startDirIndex} 
        OR ${pos} GREATER ${startDirIndex} )

        list( APPEND __SRC_DIR__ ${item} )
        #message(STATUS "DIR:${item}")

    elseif( ${pos} GREATER 2 )

        list( APPEND __SRC_LIST__ ${item} )
        #message(STATUS "SRC:${item}")

    endif( ${pos} EQUAL ${startDirIndex} 
        OR ${pos} GREATER ${startDirIndex} )

    math(EXPR pos "${pos}+1")
endforeach(item ${ARGV})

#message(STATUS "__SRC_LIST__: ${__SRC_LIST__}")
#message(STATUS "__SRC_DIR__: ${__SRC_DIR__}")

#set( SOURCE_EXTENTION cpp c C CPP)
set( SOURCE_EXTENTION cpp )
#list( APPEND SOURCE_EXTENTION ${CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS} ${CMAKE_C_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS} )

#message(STATUS "SOURCE_EXTENTION: ${SOURCE_EXTENTION}")

set( temp_list "" )

foreach( dir ${__SRC_DIR__} )
    foreach( src ${__SRC_LIST__} )
        set( cand_src )
        foreach( postfix ${SOURCE_EXTENTION})
            set( cand_src "${dir}/${src}.${postfix}" )
            file(GLOB result ${cand_src} )
            if( NOT ${result} STREQUAL "" )
                list( APPEND temp_list ${result} )                    
            endif( NOT ${result} STREQUAL "" )                            
        endforeach( postfix ${SOURCE_EXTENTION})
    endforeach( src ${__SRC_LIST__} )
endforeach( dir ${__SRC_DIR__} )

set( ${resultSource} ${temp_list} )

#message(STATUS "temp_list: ${temp_list}")
```

endmacro( vpath resultSource NumOfSource NumOfDir sourceList DirList )

Comment: Hmm, why do you need it? Can you show code of this macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I think. Full disclaimer: I'm not really a `cmake` guru, and this answer is solely based on my research after reading the question. I don't have a project to test this on, and I have never used `vpath` in a `Makefile` that I've written.

In addition, this question does not post an example `Makefile`, nor does it post the macro used by the OP, which makes me hesitant about giving a "use this" answer, but here goes.

**Firstly: *why* are we using `vpath` in our `Makefile`?**
Because I didn't know what `vpath` was, I looked it up. From the [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Directory-Search), section 4.5:

> The directory search features of make facilitate this by searching several directories automatically to find a prerequisite...
>   Similar to the `VPATH` variable, but more selective, is the `vpath` directive (note lower case), which allows you to specify a search path for a particular class of file names: those that match a particular pattern. Thus you can supply certain search directories for one class of file names and other directories (or none) for other file names.

So, you're using `vpath` to find files that are spread over several directories. These files, I'm further presuming, are either source files or are intermediate files created during the build process.

I found several examples of `vpath`, which seem indicative of it's usage - [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446634/makefile-vpath-not-working-for-header-files), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365305/flat-object-file-directory-structure-output-with-gnu-make) and finally, [Managing Projects with GNU make, 3rd Edition](http://www.makelinux.net/make3/make3-CHP-2-SECT-3) section 2.3.

So that's **why** you'd be using `vpath`. So, moving on:

**Secondly, how do you achieve the same thing using `cmake`**. And this is where further input from the OP would be helpful.

If you have *multiple targets* that you are building from a directory structure like this:

```
|- library1/
|-- {C++ Source}
|- Tool/
|-- {C++ Source}
|- Project/
|-- src/
|---- {C++ Source}
```

You should be using multiple `CMakeLists.txt`, one in each of the subdirectories. In `library1`, you'd build the library (`ADD_LIBRARY( libNAME src1.cxx src2.cxx src3.cxx )`), in `Tool` you'd add an executable (`ADD_EXECUTABLE( theTOOL src1.cxx src2.cxx )`). Finally, in `Project/src/` you'd build your project executable with the `ADD_EXECUTABLE`, linking it to `libNAME` that you've built in `library1`.

In this scenario, you *never need to search*, because your source is **explicitly** placed in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

If you are **not** doing something like the above, and your source is just spread over many many directories, something like this:

```
|-Project/
|--src/
|----maths/
|------ { SOURCE FILES }
|----sound/
|------ { SOURCE FILES }
|----imagegeneration/
|------ { SOURCE FILES }
```

In this case, you're only building the one thing, and you're just spreading your source out for ease-of-use. In this case, there are several options for you.

1. You can use the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201154/cmake-automatically-add-all-files-in-a-folder-to-a-target) to automatically add all files of a type to a target. This is **NOT** supposed to be done! From the `cmake --help-command file` (emphasis mine):

   > GLOB will generate a list of all files that match the globbing expressions and store it into the variable ... We do **not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree**.

   [See below for the reason why]
2. You can use the `add_subdirectory` directive to add multiple subdirectories, one for each of your source subdirectory. This is also not ideal. (Some supporting documentation: a [link](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=81509) which discusses the use of `add_subdirectory` in this manner)
3. You can use the `aux_source_directory` to collect the source files from the specified directory and store in a variable. (Read `cmake --help-command aux_source_directory` if you're interested in it). However, this, too, is **not** recommended.

**So *why* shouldn't you use (1), (2) or (3)?**
`cmake` is not a *replacement* for `make` or `Makefiles`. Rather, `cmake` *generates* a `build system`, which you then use to build your project. This is a distinction worth noting. While you could easily add multiple sources to your `CMakeLists.txt` automatically, you will cause an ambiguity for `cmake`: `cmake` will be unable create a build system that is aware of source files to determine what has changed!

This is the issue with all three methods mentioned above. From `cmake --help-command aux_source_directory`:

> While this seems to work,
>          there is no way for CMake to generate a build system that knows when a
>          new source file has been added.  Normally the generated build system
>          knows when it needs to rerun CMake because the CMakeLists.txt file is
>          modified to add a new source.  When the source is just added to the
>          directory without modifying this file, one would have to manually
>          rerun CMake to generate a build system incorporating the new file.

**Summation: how should you add source files to `cmake`?**

When using `cmake`, you should be **explicitly** adding source files to each of your `CMakeLists.txt`. If you are using multiple directories to separate logical pieces of code, that should be explicitly set in a `CMakeLists.txt`, something similar to the following:

```
set ( MyApplication_SRC_FILES
    maths/a.cpp
    maths/b.cpp
    sound/c.cpp
    sound/d.cpp
    imagegeneration/e.cpp
    imagegeneration/f.cpp
)
ADD_EXECUTABLE ( MyApplication ${MyApplication_SRC_FILES} )
```

This then allows `cmake` to generate a build system which can build your code. There are appropriate methods to add numerous files in directories to the build system, outlined in (1), (2) and (3) above; but they should be treated with caution and not used just because "that's how I did it with my `Makefile`". You don't write the build system itself; this is a step back from the `Makefile`, and as such should be treated slightly differently.

Comment: Thank you. legacy makefile have too many source, So I can not rewrite your suggest option- 1,2,3 - I write some macro. it have some strange. i write below.