# make vpath and header files

Tags: g++, makefile

I was learning about `make`'s `vpath` recently and I stumbled upon this question:

[Makefile vpath not working for header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446634/makefile-vpath-not-working-for-header-files)

Is there any point of using `make`'s `vpath` for header (.h) files when the header files/directory still need to be included for `g++` by using `-I`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason I can think to add the "include" directory (for `.h` files) to the `vpath` would be for dependency checking.

Your `.c` files should depend on all of the `.h` files they include - so if you change a header file, all compilation units that include that might be affected are re-built.

Lets say you have a `src/` directory for all of your `.c` files, and an `include/` directory for all of your `.h` files. By using `vpath` for `include/`, and adding a `-I` include path for `g++`, you can simply refer to all the header files by name (in the Makefile), and not have to be concerned with their paths.

Comment: Can't you just refer to them by name anyway without the vpath once you do a `-Iinclude/`?

Comment: Edited: (in the Makefile)

Comment: Oh, interesting. Do you think dependency checking for .h files is useful considering `g++` will tell you if you're missing a header file anyway?

Comment: @Tek absolutely! Please re-read my second paragraph. Makefiles are all about keeping things *up-to-date* -- think re-building, not just building the first time.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention besides that. But to be clear on that matter, you mean to tell me that without the dependency checking it won't rebuild lets say an object `.o` when the header is changed?

Comment: Nope. If you have only `foo.o: foo.c`, how would Make know to look at the timestamp on `someother.h`?  That said, you *can* do things with [automatic dependency generation](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html).